# <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077417:SSL

Tags: python, ssl, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, kodi

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

```
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1
```

I get the erro when using requests or urllib2, I'm running the code on Kodi. The code runs fine when I run it on Visual Studio on my PC.

I am trying to scrape a website that is blocked by my ISP, so I'm using a proxy version of the site.

```
import requests

url = 'https://kickass.unblocked.pe/'
r = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Did you use the proxied version on the Visual studio too?

Comment: @ρss Yes, it worked fine.

Comment: Try `verify=False` in your code. Please post the code if possible.

Comment: Still getting the same exception with `verify=False` My code is in the original post. @ρss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site is hosted by Cloudflare Free SSL and requires support for [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). SNI is support with Python 2.7 only since version 2.7.9. I guess that you are using an older version.

`verify=False` (which is usually a bad idea anyway) will not help here  because without SNI the handshake will fail because the server does not know which certificate is requested and thus will not sent any certificate but instead an alert.

Comment: Oh dear, Kodi runs Python 2.7.8 ...back to the drawing board.

Comment: For anyone interested, a ticket was raised for this: [->here<-](http://trac.kodi.tv/ticket/15883)

Comment: Newest Kodi builds are already using python version 2.7.10
See https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/pull/8207

Comment: If your running OpenElec you will have to wait for the Jarvis release (Python 2.7.11).

Comment: OMG... I have lost an entire day on this problem. Same exact scenario, code works perfectly in every other Python interpreter except Kodi. Running in Kodi always returns

`URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error>`


Unfortunately I have a wide range of Kodi devices and upgrading to a development build is not an option. I guess I have to wait until there's a stable Kodi release that fixes this issue.