# TensorFlow (Mac OS X) installation: URLError

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

**OS X version:** 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

**TensorFlow version:** 9.0

After installing pip, I proceeded to install TensorFlow following the instructions under "Pip installation" from [TensorFlow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation).

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

then

```
sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

However, even though I copied and pasted the command, I received "URLError".

> sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
>   Downloading/unpacking https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl
>     Error  while getting https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl
>   Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 266, in run
>       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1033, in prepare_files
>       self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1161, in unpack_url
>       retval = unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, self.download_dir)
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 534, in unpack_http_url
>       resp = _get_response_from_url(target_url, link)
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 569, in _get_response_from_url
>       resp = urlopen(target_url)
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 143, in **call**
>       response = self.get_opener(scheme=scheme).open(url)
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
>       response = self._open(req, data)
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
>       '_open', req)
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 123, in https_open
>       return self.do_open(self.specialized_conn_class, req)
>     File "/Users/user-name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
>       raise URLError(err)
>   URLError: 
>   Storing complete log in /Users/user-name/.pip/pip.log

Comment: On the [Tensor Flow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) website the url is different than what you posted. Have you tried using the url on the website? Also did you create the environment variable `TF_BINARY_URL` using the `export` command?

Comment: I tried to install Tensorflow 9.0 and 8.0, both gave me the same error. I just edited the post to reflect 9.0 installation instruction. Thanks

Comment: Strange; it seems to work for me. Are you able to successfully download that URL with "wget" or "curl"? I'm guessing something is strange about your network setup. Does anything interesting appear in the log (/Users/user-name/.pip/pip.log)?

Comment: pip.log actually show the message above (behind Exception: "Traceback (most recent call last):" )

Answer (score 0):

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513784/urlopen-error-errno-1-ssl-c510-error14077417ssl) from Stackoverflow. The accepted answer suggested the cause of "urlopen error" may be the older version of python. After updating python from 2.7.5 to 2.7.12, the problem is solved.