# Django Start Project Error

Tags: python, django, cmd

I currently try to add Cartoview to the existing GeoNode installation. I just followed the [tutorial](https://cartologic.github.io/installation_windows/) from the documentation to create a new project for Cartoview using the command:

```
django-admin.py startproject --template=https://github.com/cartologic/cartoview-project-template/archive/master.zip --name django.env,uwsgi.ini,.bowerrc webcartoview
```

And it comes up the following error from the command prompt:

[image]

I have successfully installed the Cartoview library (`pip install cartoview`). But I am not quite understanding what the error message means. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<urlopen error \[Errno 1\] \_ssl.c:510: error:14077417:SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513784/urlopen-error-errno-1-ssl-c510-error14077417ssl)

Comment: @KishorPawar although the error is indeed the same one, implementing it in this case would involve changing code in the Django framework, a feat I would not recommend. For that reason I don't think the answer suggested there is helpful.

Comment: @Shadow, I doubt the solution asks to change the code. It talks about installing a compatible version of python I guess.

Comment: @KishorPawar upon rereading it- your right. It does indeed mention the version of python. I just missed that detail.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that error before - it was caused by a server using a newer version of SSL than my client supported.

For a quick workaround - download the zip file yourself and place it on the server so you can reference it directly.

If possible though, updating your operating system will mean that this command will work, and you'll also be more up to date with security patches and the like. That said, I suspect you may get away with just updating your python version.